# Integral question related to i.i.d. random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, integration, probability-distributions

I am stuck on this question, I would appreciate any
hint I can get to understand this!

We have $(\Omega, M, P)$ a probability space. $X_1$ and $X_2$
are i.i.d. and let $S_2 = X_1 + X_2$.

For given any real number $d$, I would like to show that
$$
\int_{S_2 < d} X_1 \ dP = \int_{S_2 < d} X_2 \ dP.
$$

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The random variable $1_{X_1 + X_2 < d} X_1$ has the same distribution as $1_{X_1 + X_2  < d} X_2$ since $X_1$ and $X_2$ are i.i.d. And so they have the same expectation.

Comment: Could you possibly explain me why they are i.i.d.? Thanks!

Comment: @TomMosher: that's your assumption, isn't it?

Comment: I meant for $1_{X_1+X_2<d} X_i$'s, but I have actually figured it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since $X_1$ and $X_2$ are iid, you can write
$$ \int_{S<d} X_1 dP = \int_\mathbb R \int_\mathbb R x_1 \ 1 \{ x_1+ x_2 < d \} d \mu(x_1) d \mu(x_2)   $$
where $\mu$ is the common distribution of $X_1$, and $X_2$. You obtain the same thing with $\int_{S < d} X_2 dP$ as $x_1$ and $x_2$ are just dummy variables here.

Comment: Could you possibly explain me how to get the formula exactly? Are we using convolution of measures here? Thanks!

Comment: Your integral is over $\Omega$:
$$ \int_{S <d} X_1 dP = \int_{\omega: S(\omega) < d} X_1(\omega) dP(\omega)    $$
You do the change of variable $(x_1,x_2) = (X_1(\omega),X_2(\omega))$ and you get to the result, as $\mu \otimes \mu$ is the pushforward measure of $P$ through the map $\omega \mapsto X_1(\omega), X_2(\omega)$ by the independence assumption.

Comment: I see. Thank you very much! Greatly appreciated!